# How to assign a pre-defined style to a asp:BulletedList link

Tags: html, asp.net, css, bulletedlist

I have some link styles in my stylesheet:

```
a.whiteLinks {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.blueLinks {
    color: #0076AC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.whiteLinks:hover {
    color: #5397AD;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.blueLinks:hover {
    color: #5397AD;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have the following `asp:BulletedList`

```
<asp:BulletedList DisplayMode="HyperLink" runat="server" ID="blFirst" ClientIDMode="Static">
     <asp:ListItem Value="allergy.aspx">Allergy and Immunology</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="">Anesthesiology</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="">Breast Surgery</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Where can I edit so the links inside the bulleted list uses the `blueLink` style rather than the default one?

I tried to add `CssClass="blueLinks"` in the `BulletedList` but it didn't have any affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the class to

```
.blueLinks li a {
   color: #0076AC;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

and adjust the hover as well so that you also have that mapped the right way

```
 .blueLinks li a:hover {
     color: #5397AD;
     outline:none; /* add this. ASP has the bad habit of adding outline to links in IE */
     text-decoration: none; /* You don't need this.  */
  }
```

[***YOUR FIDDLE ***](http://jsfiddle.net/pAuPL/3/)

Comment: I am also using the same style for my `a` links on my pages and wanted the same style for this specific bulleted list. I changed from `a.blueLinks` to `.blueLinks` to no avail. Still not changing the style.

Comment: Can you extract the html and css and post it in fiddle? Did you try it out statically (outside of ASP). I'm pretty sure it can be done by mapping the route of the specificity the right way. It's hard to tell without knowing what else is around this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pAuPL/ It won't render correctly as it's ASP code and I will check if it works without ASP...

Comment: right, you need to paste the source code. run it in a browser and find trouble area in the source, paste it in the fiddle.

Comment: I had to add it to blFirst style and it's working. Extra code!

Comment: wait wait, don't do that...don't style the Id. Always style the class as you can reuse them. Id's can only be used once

Comment: I edited my answer. It's a matter of mapping the right way to target the a inside the li

Comment: It will for every a link inside a list that is using that class. If you want it to apply to all a links, simply add those properties in that class to the reset.css where the a { code here } is